# Проблема с геокодом react-yandex-maps

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api, mobx-react-lite

Моя функция, которая по определенным координатам,выдает название адреса,но при каждом клике срабатывает reverse, и поэтому после второго клика по маркеру, он меняет местами данные в геокоде и выдаёт некорректный адрес, как сохранить только первое нажатие на маркер и больше не вызывать данную функцию ?

```js
 {state.map((coordinates, idx) =>
              <Placemark
              onClick = {()=> {
                  store.writePoint(coordinates);
                  console.log(coordinates);
}}
                key={idx}
                geometry={coordinates}
                options={{
                  iconLayout: 'default#image',
                  iconImageSize: [18, 18],
                  iconImageHref: pointImg,
                }}
              />)
            }
```

```js
  async writePoint(coordinates){
       
       const result = []
    const res = await fetch(`https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=${YMAPS_KEY}&format=json&geocode=${coordinates.reverse()}`)
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data)
    result.push(data.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember[0].GeoObject.name)
    console.log(result)
        this.data.destination = result
        
    }
```

Comment: Из первого, что пришло в голову - сделать переменную-флаг и условие в writePoint, которое этот флаг проверяет. При срабатывании writePoint флаг менять, чтобы второй раз уже не срабатывало :)

Answer (score 1):

Некорректно составил функцию, нужно было добавить условие с методом every() и в итоге все получилось)

```js
 async writePoint(coordinates){
       
       const result = []
    const res = await fetch(`https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=${YMAPS_KEY}&format=json&geocode=${coordinates.reverse()}`)
    const data = await res.json();
    
    if (this.data.destination.length !== 0 && this.data.destination.every(() => data.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember[0].GeoObject.name))
    return
    result.push(data.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember[0].GeoObject.name)
    this.data.destination = result
    }
```